# How would I expose weight for a custom select field to Drupal Views for sorting?

Tags: custom-fields, drupal-views, drupal-7

I have a custom select option field with about 35 options.
I'd like to be able to sort the field in Drupal Views by weight instead of value or name.

I looked around for the views integration in the core files but couldn't find the section that exposes custom field option groups to views.

I would assume that it is in all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/views/components/civicrm.core.inc but I don't see any mention there.

Custom option groups appear to be exposed in all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/views/civicrm.views.inc but I don't see any mention of the option_value table to add the weight column.

Any suggestions on how to expose the weight of individual custom select options in Views?

Thank you!

Comment: it may be evident based on your links but worth being clear if D7 or D8

Comment: This particular install is D7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Views CiviCRM Expose Tables](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_civicrm_expose_tables) module to join to CiviCRM tables and columns that aren't otherwise exposed.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I might try that if I could figure out how to use the module! But after install, I don't see any links to it and clicking on the configure link in modules just takes me to the main views screen. However, the table is already joined somewhere because it's getting the list of options when I add it as an exposed filter.